# How to change mysql port number in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

How can i can change port number of mysql from 3306 to mychoice number(1023) in ubuntu 13.10. 
I tried by editing the port nuber in file: /etc/mysql/my.cnf. But after this change mysql never start .
Please guide me how can i do this .

Comment: That is the way to go usually. What is the error returned when changing this value?

Comment: Error is nothing.. After modification in file mysqlserver not starting . When I use the mysql in terminal it display error message ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: better if you try this question on ubuntu forums of Stack Exchange. As it is programming specific forum.

Answer (score 1):

Open /etc/mysql/my.cnf in vi editor

```
# vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

change port

```
port=1023
```

Save and close the file. 
Finally, restart mysqld:

```
# service mysqld restart
```

Comment: i tried this but after this mysql service not restarted. cursor just blinking in terminal "mysql stop/waiting" shown .

Answer (score 0):

Just Posted Question in askubuntu.com .. The Ans is 1023 is reserved for TCP UPD .
I changed to 9999 It worked for me .. Thanks Everyone 
Here 's link 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/407847/how-to-change-mysql-port-number-in-ubuntu